# Request initiator chain contains old CDN

Tags: plugins, cache, cdn

I changed the domain of my wordpress page (everything else works fine so far) and also the CDN provider, still in my dev tools I'm getting an error for one js-file [image: network][image: initiator]

I use Autoptimize and WP Super Cache, changed all the CDN entries there and also downloaded all the files from the hosting server with a FTP tool and did a full text search if there are any links to the old CDN left, but still this pops up...

all other files are served fine from the new CDN...

Does anyone have an idea where this could come from? The request URL looks also a bit wierd...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s possible the script is coming from the database. If you have access to WP CLI, you can use [the `db search` command](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/db/search/) to search for occurrences in the database, and then [the `search-replace` command](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/search-replace/) to update the occurrences.

You’ll likely also want to consider searching for `https://https://`, as that appears to be occurring in the script’s URL.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to find the string in the backend SQL, I have no idea how I could have missed that. It was a third plugin using the wrong CDN URL.

Comment: You’re welcome! ‍♂️